# Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (scheduledDate): Must be a date in the future: Instance of 'TZDateTime'

Tags: flutter, notifications

This is me trying to create a daily scheduled notification using flutter_local_notification. I've tried changing the time and uses different methods such as using TZDateTime.from instead of TZDateTime.utc and yet it still doesn't fix anything. Here's the code:

```
        import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
        import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

        \\\

        const platform = const MethodChannel('helper');

        tz.initializeTimeZones();
        final String timeZoneName = 'Asia/Bangkok';
        tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));

        final tzTime = tz.TZDateTime.utc(time.year, time.month, time.day, i, time.minute + 1, time.second);

        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
            0,
            'Shouter Clock',
            "It's $dateTime",
            tzTime,
            platformChannelSpecifics,
            payload: "Test",
          androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
          uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        );
```

Comment: What is type of `tz` variable?

Comment: What timezone of device/emulator/simulator where you testing app? If timezones differ, you `tzTime` in the past of date on device.

Comment: @fartem I believe it's in the same timezone already but I'll check it again

Comment: Yep it's in the correct timezone

Comment: You can try to debug your app and compare dates at runtime. Android Studio and VS Code provide feature to getting values from variables when the app is running.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion , It's throwing this error because of the time which you selected is before than now . In their pub.dev page , there is an example for solve this problem .

```
tz.TZDateTime _nextInstanceOfTenAM() {
final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate =
    tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year, now.month, now.day, 10);
if (scheduledDate.isBefore(now)) {
  scheduledDate = scheduledDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
}
return scheduledDate;
}
```

It's the example [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/example) from their pub.dev page